# How to refresh listbox in mvc razor with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, listbox

i have a form with multiple select items in listbox.
and then, when i edit data in gridview using ajax, i want to make sure selected item is checked or not from ajax return.
here are the images for your references. i hope you know what i mean. Thank you

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.listbox').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        maxHeight: '400',
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        onChange: function (element, checked) {
            var brands = $('.listbox option:selected');
            var selected = [];
            $(brands).each(function (index, brand) {
                selected.push([$(this).val()]);
            });
        },
        buttonText: function (options, select) {
            return 'Selected User';
        }
    });
});

function OnClickEdit(s, e, GetDetailId) {            
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("OnClickEditAction")',
        data: {
            GetDetailId: GetDetailId
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //=>  HERE SET REFRESH LISTBOX <=\\
            var getData = data.PopulateData[0];                  
            var alfa = data.PopulateData[0].Users;
            //$(".listbox").multiselect('destroy');
            //$(".listbox").multiselect;
            //console.log(alfa);
            //$.each(alfa, function (i) {
            //    console.log(alfa[i]);
            //    console.log(alfa[i]['Selected']);
            //    console.log(alfa[i]['Text']);
            //    console.log(alfa[i]['Value']);
            //}); 
        }
    }); 
}
</script> 

 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.UserIds, Model.Users, new { @class = "listbox" })
```

Comment: basically what you want from your question?

Comment: you shouldn't have to refresh the listbox since you're doing an ajax call on the grid. you'll have to reload the data for the grid, but the listbox should stay at its current state.

Comment: @Dhiren : I want to display the items selected in the listbox, the result of ajax process.

Comment: @dickrichie : this is the edit process, from the grid view to the form. where I have to make the items in the list box checked according to the previous input.

Comment: @user2538170 Ok so you want to check or make selections in list checkbox when form is opened in edit mode. Correct?

Comment: @Dhiren : yes correct...

Comment: `var brands = $('.listbox option');
            $.each(alfa,function(data){
            $(brands).each(function (index, brand) {
                if(brand.innerHTML == data.UserName){
                brand.prop("checked",true);}
            });
})`
check other property if innerhtml won't work

Answer (score 0):

i found the solutions to this case :

```
                        $(".listbox").multiselect('destroy'); 
                        var GetListUserSelected = data.PopulateData[0].Users;  
                        //console.log(GetListUserSelected);
                        var isList = $('.listbox');
                        isList.empty();
                        $.each(GetListUserSelected, function (i) {
                            var isVal = GetListUserSelected[i]['Value'];
                            var isText = GetListUserSelected[i]['Text'];
                            var isCheck = GetListUserSelected[i]['Selected'];

                            if (isCheck) {
                                isList.append($("<option value=" + isVal + " selected=selected>" + isText + "</option>"));
                            } else {
                                isList.append($("<option value=" + isVal + ">" + isText + "</option>"));
                            } 

                        });  
                        $('.listbox').multiselect({
                            includeSelectAllOption: true,
                            selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
                            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
                            enableFiltering: true,
                            maxHeight: '400',
                            buttonWidth: '100%',
                            onChange: function (element, checked) {
                                var brands = $('.listbox option:selected');
                                var selected = [];
                                $(brands).each(function (index, brand) {
                                    selected.push([$(this).val()]); 
                                });
                            },
                            buttonText: function (options, select) {
                                return 'Selected User';
                            }
                        });
```

thanks....